# Salesforce One: can I call another Android App by startActivityForResult from HTML5 (JS)?

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-app, html5, android

I want my Salesforce1 App uses another Android App seamlessly. It is easy if we have access to App code, but with Salesforce1 we have not.

So, can I call another Android App by **startActivityForResult from HTML5 (JS)** and get a result back?

Thank you a lot for any piece of advice.

Comment: Got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported. Depending on your use case, you could try one of the URL Schemes for the Salesforce App.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213748&type=1

or

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce1_url_schemes.pdf